# What is the easiest way to get latest versions of the same value within a pandas dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'xx_foo_yyy bar_xyz xx_foo_yyy_1 bar_xyz_1 xx_foo_yyy_3 bar_xyz_2 xx_foo_yyy_2 baz'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split()})

print(df)
```

```
       A         B
0  xx_foo_yyy    one
1  bar_xyz       one
2  xx_foo_yyy_1  two
3  bar_xyz_1     three
4  xx_foo_yyy_3  two
5  bar_xyz_2     two
6  xx_foo_yyy_2  one
7  baz           three
```

And I want to filter only for the latest version of the values in column 'A'. So the output I am looking to get is as follows:

```
     A 
4  xx_foo_yyy_3
5  bar_xyz_2
7  baz
```

What would be the easiest way to get the desired output?

[Below is sample of actual data (some letters have been replaced) - there is 42400 records in the original dataset.]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the latest version not including where there is only "one"?

Comment: If there's only one version of the value I'd like to see it in the output as well. so in the example given, I would like to see "baz" in the output.

Comment: I think you can solve this by separate column `A` to 2 columns. One is string starting from "_" to the end. The other is the what remain. Then it would be easier to solve

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
m = df['A'].str.replace(r'_\d+$', '', regex=True)

idx = (df.assign(id=df['A'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna(0))
       .astype({'id': int}).groupby(m)['id'].idxmax())
```

```
print(df.loc[idx].sort_index())

              A      B
4  xx_foo_yyy_3    two
5     bar_xyz_2    two
7           baz  three
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting the following error when I try your solution: "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long"

Comment: @AhmedD. You `A` column is not `_n` like?

Comment: A more accurate representation of the actual data would be:

       A                     B
0    xx_foo_yyy      one
1    bar_xyz           one
2  xx_foo_yyy_1    two
3  bar_xyz_1         three
4  xx_foo_yyy_3    two
5  bar_xyz_2         two
6  xx_foo_yyy_2    one
7    yy_baz            three

and the desired output would be:

     A 
4  xx_foo_yyy_3
5  bar_xyz_2
7  yy_baz

Comment: @AhmedD. include the data in the question and not as a comment

Comment: @AhmedD. you changed the original data, making this answer void. You could consider adding the data and its expected output, instead of deleting the previous data. The output righn now is for the previous data. Consider maintaining the previous data with its output and adding the new data with its output

Comment: My apologies, this is the first time I post a question on here and I have already edited the original question to reflect the actual data more accurately. Appreciate if we could look at the updated question instead.

Comment: @AhmedD. Updated the answer, but I guess your `int` conversion problem doesn't reflect on your current data.

Comment: Yes I am still getting the same error which seems to be caused by the following portion of your code: 

df.assign(id=df['A'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna(0))
       .astype({'id': int})

I am not sure what is causing the error. Would it be helpful if I provide a sample of the actual data?

Comment: @AhmedD. Is the output of `df['A'].str.extract('_(\d+)$')` all integer?

Comment: When I run the following code (using actual column name):
'''
print(df2['tableName'].str.extract('_(\d+)$'))
'''
I get the following output:
'''
         0
0        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
...    ...
42395  NaN
42396    1
42397  NaN
42398    1
42399  NaN

[42400 rows x 1 columns]
'''

Comment: @AhmedD. How about the output of `df.loc[~df['A'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna(0).str.isnumeric(), 'A']`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, that is giving the following error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' 

Which appears to be caused by the following portion of the code:

df2['tableName'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna(0).str

Comment: @AhmedD. Try `df.loc[~(df['A'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna('0')[0].str.isdigit()), 'A']` this one.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, the output of the following code:

df2.loc[~(df2['tableName'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna('0')[0].str.isdigit()), 'tableName']

is this:

Series([], Name: tableName, dtype: object)

Comment: @AhmedD. Then I don't understand why it gives the overflow error since all the numbers are digit. How about `astype({'id': 'int64'})'`?

Comment: if I run this:

m = df2['tableName'].str.replace(r'_\d+$', '', regex=True)
idx = (df2.assign(id=df2.loc[~(df2['tableName'].str.extract('_(\d+)$').fillna('0')[0].str.isdigit()), 'tableName'])
       .astype({'id': 'int64'}).groupby(m)['id'].idxmax())

I get this error:

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I've added a sample of the actual data in the question body to help with the solution.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, hope you had a great weekend. Could you give some pointers as to what seems to be causing the errors? I've added a sample of the actual data that may expose the issue.

Comment: @AhmedD. This is because your given example data and your real data are different.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, how can we adjust the code for the real data?